# Convert DateTime to timestamp in bash

Tags: bash

I have a DateTime 2019-02-03T10:17:24Z to be converted to timestamp.
I can convert a regular dateTime to timestamp using 
current="`date +%s`"

OS: MAC
Bash : GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)

I tried using different formats, but it is throwing illegal date format.

```
created="2019-02-03T10:17:24Z"
createdT=`date -j -f +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ $created`
```

Comment: `createdT="$(date -d "${created}" +%s)"`?

Comment: Looks like you're using BSD date rather than GNU date. Can you confirm your OS and version of bash?

Comment: OS: macOS
version: 10.13.3 (17D102)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have two problems.

1. Usage. The `-f` option doesn't take a plus sign ("`+`") at the beginning of the format.
2. The format you've specified appears to require a nanosecond value as would be provided by GNU date, but this value is not in your input data.

Note:

```
$ created="2019-02-03T10:17:24Z"
$ date -j -f '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' "$created" '+%s'
1549207044
```

Note that it's a really good idea to use quotes -- single quotes where you can, double quotes where you need to expand variables.

Comment: When I execute the same command inside Ubuntu:16.04 container.. It throws the following error....  
**date: invalid option -- 'j'** .  
What is the equivalent command in ubuntu??  
@ghoti

Comment: In Ubuntu this works `createdT=$(date -d "${created}" '+%s')`